# Telegram message_handler Python

Tags: python, telegram

I've got a really simple message_handler thing in my code which I expect to work this way:

If user says "YES" then bot asks for first name and then for a second name. However, I don't get to ask first name and second name. But instead, my output would be:

> First Name: YES Second Name: YES

How can I fix this?

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def handle_text(message):
    if message.text == 'YES':
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Your first Name")
        FirstName = message.text
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Your second Name")
        SecondName = message.text
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "First Name: " + str(FirstName) + " Second Name: " + str(SecondName))
```

Comment: `message` never changes from the message that was sent in, so `message.text` is always 'YES'.  You need some way of receiving the user's response to the first name and last name messages.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [FSM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine). Some libraries (for example [aiogram](https://github.com/aiogram/aiogram)) has built-in instruments and [examples](https://github.com/aiogram/aiogram/blob/master/examples/finite_state_machine_example.py) of usage.

But if your library don't have FSM - you can make your own simple state machine. Just save user step to the dictionary.

```
states = {}  # key - user_id, value - state

def abstract_handler(...):
    if not states.get(user_id):
        # ask user about his first name here
        states[user_id] = 'first name'
        return

    if states.get(user_id) == 'first name':
        first_name = message.text
        # ask about second name here
        states[user_id] = 'second name'
        return

    if states.get(user_id) == 'second name':
        second_name = message.text
        # etc
```

P.S.: it's just simple explanation of process. You can split this code to several handlers. And don't forget to save user data.

P.P.S: don't call variables with CamelCase :)